# How can I force the login to a specific ip address

Tags: authentication

I have 20 stores in different locations that want to login to a punch in(Employee/Hours) application. How can I force them all 20 stores to login from the same computer/store every day? I am working with .net but other solutions maybe consider.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You have 20 logins to one site and you want to "bind" those logins to 20 different computers, or?

Comment: As I understand, do you want that an employee only can login from the same location?

Comment: After you clarify your question, could you also explain why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Create a web application and all 20 stores can access it, thus login would be on the same machine = web server. If that's what you're asking.

Comment: ok that still doesn't make sense :-) hope you figured it out after 18 months ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some possible answers based on interpretation of question:

1) Lock the program down based on the computer's MAC address at each location. This would allow you to only allow the program to run on the one computer at each location.

2) If you want only the stores to connect to your server, then you can restrict access to only specific IP address using routers and firewalls.